# Add empty line to string

Tags: java, android, string

How can I add an empty line to a string?
So that a string looking like this:

```
This is an example of something
This is still an example of something
```

Becomes this:

```
This is an example of something

This is still an example of something
```

Comment: Have you try using "\n"..?

Comment: Or "\r\n" or System.getProperty("line.separator")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"This is an example of something\n\nThis is still an example of something"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
"This is an example of something\n\nThis is still an example of something"
```

Comment: Can't possibly take 1 minute to copy and format and add a line and post ! I began when there were no answers posted yet !

Comment: @StinePike He may not see the answer..Not comment anybody like this, because that word will hurt them.. I am sorry if I hurt you with this comment

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't want to hurt anyone. Actually I am not eligible enough to correct others. I just saw the same sentence. Thats why I couldnt resist to post such comment.. sorry mates

Answer (score 2):

Just add "\n" to your string or br tag if you going to use as formating and displying in UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, Where you replace every "\n" with "\n\n".

```
str = str.replaceAll("\n", "\n\n");
```

str is your string you get from your editText.